# Unset a property from codebehind

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties

I have this TextBox that has a MaxHeight value of 62 by default in my XAML file, and I want to programmatically unset it from codebehind on a certain event. Sadly, this:

```
myTextBox.MaxHeight = 0;
```

actually sets the maximum height to zero... making it invisible. Isn't there a method on UI elements to purely **unset** a specific property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it back to it's default value:

```
myTextBox.MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
```

This allows the text box to grow to "any height".

Comment: Oh! Okay. Yes, I should've looked for the default value indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to reset any dependency property to its default value, without explicitly specifying (or even knowing) the value. Just call [`ClearValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597464%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
myTextBox.ClearValue(FrameworkElement.MaxHeightProperty);
```

Note however that this clears the [local value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265148%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#listing) of the property. If there is any value set by a Template or Style Setter, that value will be effective then.